# Django pass variable to URL tag

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I am using Django 1.11. I am trying to add a link to a DeleteView template from the UpdateView. There is probably a better way to acheive this than the way I am attempting but I am new to Django and so the way i'm trying is to use a URL to direct to `myapp/<pk>/delete/`

In my template I have `{% url 'calendar_delete' pk=event_id %}`

In my model I have

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

In my URLs I have

```
url(r'^calendar/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$',views.CalendarDelete.as_view(),name='calendar_delete'),
```

With the code as above the template doesnt render due to
NoReverseMatch exception. '{'pk': ''}' not found, so its obviously not picking up the event_id from the model. When I hardcode a number in there it will render and the URL will direct me to the DeleteView template.

Can anyone advise how I can get the `<pk>/event_id` into the URL tag?

The `<pk>` exists in the URL of the UpdateView template and I have also tried to extract it from the URL as a variable and pass to the URL tag. I can extract ok but not pass in the variable.

Any help on this would be much appreciated, including advice on better methods to use for the desired outcome than I am heading down! Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure that you have value in event_id ? event_id seems to be empty.

Comment: I think it possibly isnt passing correctly. There is a value present in the model database and all of the required fields are rendering correctly in the form so I assume there is no issue with event_id in the model

Comment: In some of the visible part, try putting {{ event_id }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `UpdateView`, you should be able to access `object` in the template.

```
{% url 'calendar_delete' pk=object.pk %}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much